# How to determine likely cause of a failure in a cloud system?

Tags: bayesian, statistical-significance

I'm analyzing failures in a large cloud system, and would like to triage likely causes for a specific type of error (category, not a single incident) based on the location or other properties of the failure.

To simplify, let's say I have just one feature to consider - the data center where the type of failure that I'm analyzing happened. There are hundreds of types of errors, and millions of errors logged per day.

My data set consists of the most recent 24 hour track of failures.

From this I can extract a table that looks like this:

```
| Error type | # cases in location 1 | # cases in location 2 | # cases in location 3 | # cases in location 4 |
|--------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|
| Error type 1 | 100 | 2 | 15 | 0 |
| Error type 2 | 20 | 500 | 10 | 10 |
| Error type 3 | 90 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| Error type 4 | 92 | 9 | 11 | 5 |
| Error type 5 | 80 | 13 | 8 | 6 |
```

(etc)

If I'm interested in determining whether the cause of error type 2 is likely to be somehow connected to conditions related to location 2, it's intuitively clear that's the case due to the disproportional number of cases happening there.

What's the best way(s) to automatically detect this, preferably with a confidence score attached to it? I guess I could ask what the probability of any other error happening in location 2 vs. the same calculation for error type 2 somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up calculating the standard deviation and mean in percent + essentially normalizing it. Do this for the total population, and use as a baseline. Then for each error calculate the same, and use a cutoff based on general mean and stddev.

I went with a factor being significant if it was represented more than general mean + 1.5 * general stddev